# Multi-select error this.value is undefined

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to use the new multi-select component in Kendo UI for Angular 2 but "this.value is undefined" error is thrown in Firebug when the widget is launched.

```
<kendo-multiselect name="watchbill" [data]="watchbills" [(ngModel)]="selectedWatchbills" [textField]="'name'" [valueField]="'id'"></kendo-multiselect>

selectedWatchbills: Watchbill[];
watchbills: Watchbill[];
ngOnInit() {
        this.shipDataService.getWatchbills(this.startTime, this.endTime).subscribe(
        data => this.watchbills = data
    );
}


export interface Watchbill {
    id: string,
    name: string
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an issue with that the view is rendered before data has arrived, so try and put an `ngIf` like so:

```
<kendo-multiselect *ngIf="watchbills" name="watchbill" [data]="watchbills" 
     [(ngModel)]="selectedWatchbills" [textField]="'name'" [valueField]="'id'"></kendo-multiselect>
```

which waits for that there will be values in the array `watchbills` before rendering anything that is wrapped inside that tag.

Comment: Thanks, I have it mostly working now.  I was getting a Error: Permission denied to access property "rejection".  I fixed that by initializing the arrays in the constructor.  But the selected items don't have an 'X' to de-select them like in their examples, http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/multiselect/ What could be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you there, not familiar with kendo at all, I just answered your current question, that I figured was an async issue and could be solved with the ngIf. You would have to raise a new question for that problem, doesn't really fit this question. That way someone who is familiar with kendo can help you ;) That's my suggestion :)

Comment: Answer accepted.  I tagged kendo-ui-angular2 so in case anyone was wondering, I was using the wrong versions of bootstrap css and kendo theme css.  The following fixed it.  

`"@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.11.12",
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",`